# How to look at iPad's photo folder on a Mac?

Tags: mac, ipad

If an iPad is connected to a PC, then in My Computer, there is a iPad device containing a folder with all photos and videos.

But on a Mac with Lion, this won't happen... Finder doesn't show such device or folder -- even when I choose Preference of Finder to show every device -- is there a way to see the folder like on the PC?

(I just want to edit one video using HandBrake, so won't like to use iPhotos or iMovies to import the video, but just take the video file "as is".)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the OS X tool called [Image Capture](http://www.apple.com/osx/apps/all.html#imagecapture). It is much more lightweight than iPhoto and is for downloading images and videos from digital cameras, which the iPad technically is as well.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple! use [Disk Aid](http://www.digidna.net/products/diskaid) and transfer the video to your mac

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: there is no way not to use any 3rd party app?

Comment: No way i am aware of .. Disk Aid did the job for me , thats why i suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app called iExplorer to view the photos and videos on your Mac without using iTunes. There may be other methods involving the terminal, but to my knowledge, there's no way to avoid using a third-party product.

Answer (score 0):

If you have iPhoto, once you connect your iPad and open iPhoto, it should detect all photos on the iPad and will allow you to sync / transfer them to your computer.

You can get iPhoto to transfer the iPad photos to a folder you create, and you will be able to see all the images there. You can also view all photos on iPhoto and choose which ones you want to transfer.